# How to add padding when using imagemagick to convert an EPS into a PNG?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

How to add padding when using imagemagick to convert an EPS into a PNG?

I want to do something like:

```
convert logo.eps -size 128x128 logo.png
```

But want the actual logo to be 96x96px, centered, surrounded by a transparent background to reach 128x128 pixels.

Comment: Not a programming question; fits better on e.g. Super User.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

found it out myself:

```
convert logo.eps -background transparent -gravity center -scale 96x96 -extent 128x128 logo.png
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Do you know how to keep the background to be transparent inside the inner image 96x96? Currently the image background is white. I would also like to change the color and alpha of the image to #99333333 value to achieve Android Holo Light icon recommendation: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html. Do you know how to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: @petrsyn I found using `-background none` (instead of `-background transparent`) *before* the input file name did the trick.